# ImportError: cannot import name 'MailMerge' from 'mailmerge'

Tags: python-3.x, docx-mailmerge

I am having this problem whereby I can not copy

```
from __future__ import print_function
from mailmerge import MailMerge
from datetime import date
```

I am getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6791e9480127> in <module>
      1 from __future__ import print_function
----> 2 from mailmerge import MailMerge
      3 from datetime import date

ImportError: cannot import name 'MailMerge' from 'mailmerge' (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\mailmerge\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Jupyter Notebook

1. Open Anaconda Prompt and press '`conda install lxml`'
2. You should get that "The following packages will be UPDATED:" press 'y'
3. In your jupyter notebook write `!pip install docx-mailmerge`
4. Then you can simply write this:

   from **future** import print_function

   from mailmerge import MailMerge

   from datetime import date
5. That is all, it should work

I learned this from this [webpage](https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html)

This had solved my problem.

Answer (score 7):

The solution, assuming you want to use the newer version, is to uninstall the `mailmerge` package and install `docx-mailmerge`,like this:

```
$ pip uninstall mailmerge
$ pip install docx-mailmerge
```

after that you can import like

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge
```

You can see similar issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Bouke/docx-mailmerge/issues/58)
and docs for [docx-mailmerge](https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/)

Comment: import docx-mailmerge showed   import docx-mailmerge
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you need to import like this from mailmerge import MailMerge see my updated answer and docs of docx-mailmerge